# Function of Co-enzymes

Tags: biochemistry

Is the function of a co-enzyme to make a reaction run quicker? If catalysts speed up reactions, and enzymes are catalysts, and co-enzymes make enzymes work better, does that mean the co-enzymes just make reactions quicker?

Comment: Where coenzymes are used, they are generally required for catalysis.

Comment: What research have you done to answer this question for yourself? Have you googled for "coenzyme"? This site expects posters to demonstrate that they have put in some effort themselves.

Comment: @David I think the biggest problem with the question is that it is unclear. We need to know what enzyme/co-enzyme OP is asking about before google even enters the fray. Either way, I think the question needs to be developed further.